# Help to create a texturized material

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, normals, bump

I need help to reproduce this material with this "texture". It is a playing card, it can be vynil, or simple hard plastic. I know it is not that hard, but I still have some problems with nodes. The main objective is to replicate the bumps perfectly. I'm more interested on bumps, and this kind of "texture" than on colors or lightning. You can ignore this gradient, and even the colors white and black. Look only to the pattern of the bumps.

[image]

Thanks in advance Blender People

Comment: Hello, in this case the lighting will have a big impact on the way the material reflects light. Does your scene have a light in the top right corner or do you want the light fading effect to be "baked" into the texture ?

Comment: I'm more interested on bumps, and this kind of "texture" than on colors or lightning. You can ignore this gradient, and even the colors white and black. Look only to the pattern of the bumps. I can imagine something using the wave node, mixed with another node in another direction (90°). Like that https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/_images/render_shader-nodes_textures_wave_example.png

Comment: But I still didn't get there

Comment: Is it necessary to have it as procedural texture? If not, possibly just throw something with a flat color and similar texture (a blank playing card or a possibly a coarsely woven dish towel) on a flatbed scanner and try using the scanned image as bump texture...

Comment: Yes, I would like to create it procedural, because I don't have the object, or nothing similar, I have just this piece of image as reference.

Comment: But I'm open to try anything with ready normal/bump maps, I just don't have the object to create it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this.

[image: Material]

All I really did was warp the vectors of a couple of Noise Textures by adding the Vectors of Wave Textures using a Vector Math Node. This produces "uneven" wave lines. I made a second of the same, rotated 90 degrees with a Mapping node. so it has that crossed thatch appearance, and then increased the wave distortion slightly, so it doesn't look linear, even, and fake. I also incorporated another Noise Texture to give some underlying bumps. You can see that I lightened both the values by mixing with white before multiplying them together, but even then the effect was almost still too strong - make sure to check your strength/appearance, and mix with white when needed before connecting to the Bump Node. You might be surprised how much more realistic a "slight" effect looks compared to a "deep" one (if that makes any sense)

Lastly, I just took some Ambient Occlusion from the Wave combo and multiplied it with a neutral grey to make the ridges pop slightly more. Have a try and see if it works for you.

If you want to go one farther, you can use yet another Noise Texture to "block" some portions of the wave mix, so it's not so uniform, and thus more realistic. I also elaborated on what I mentioned before about a "slight" bump effect, by mixing the whole mix with white again before the Bump node. I also lightened the color slightly, and increased the roughness (both things also can work to reduce bump effect as well). Here is the final result of the (more complex but improved) new mix:

[image: Material3]

Comment: I gonna try that second one, can you tell me what are the two first nodes that don't appear on image please? This on left side of the image. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's the same as the first graph, I just moved things around a little to accommodate the new Noise Texture (the top one attached to the ColorRamp - it is connected to Object Texture coordinate like the rest). The MixRGB on the lefthand side is the same one that's connected directly to the Ambient Occlusion node in the first image. So to sum up, all I added was a Noise Texture, a ColorRamp, and a MixRGB to mix it with what was previously there.

Comment: So good. I got it. But to be honest I didn't mind about the base color, because I want to use it once as red, another time as blue, another as black. So to me the most important thing here, is the nodes that goes on Normal Input of the Principled BSDF Node. I'm a bit confused if you kept the first 4 nodes of the first part of the nodes (wave texture, mix, vector math and the noise texture). Can you show me all the nodes of the second image please?

Comment: Sorry, I can't show you because I already closed the file and didn't save. But, it's like I said before, the 2 graphs are identical, the only difference is I added one extra step (Another MixRGB node) to the existing connections. The new mix (second yellow node from the left) just replaces the connections that were previously connected to the first mix (leftmost yellow node). In both cases, the connections went to both the bump map and the base color.

Comment: That is ok, I got it now. Thank you